# Write a new app for phpfox

Tags: php, scripting, frameworks, phpfox

I want to create a new app for my own phpfox project.I do all as in documentation. But when I go to my app link I see this error page 
Unable to load module template: todo->controller/index.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a template in `YourApp/views/controller/index.html.php` ?

Each controller need a template with it.

Comment: I think you use wrong url. Please be more specific by capturing the file's structure and your start.php